# Openshift: get access to openshift docker registry

Tags: docker, openshift, minishift

I've exposed my openshift registry:

```
$ oc get routes -n default
NAME              HOST/PORT                                       PATH      SERVICES          PORT       TERMINATION   WILDCARD
docker-registry   docker-registry-default.192.168.99.104.nip.io             docker-registry   5000-tcp                 None
```

Nevertheless, I'm trying to get access on that registry, but I've not been able to figure out what's wrong:

```
docker login -p ngRslZJYJ40WxBA6YQbE5nMDK1Gh-cSWgnJCKR4EJ2I docker-registry-default.192.168.99.104.nip.io -u unused
```

This command keeps stuck.

Comment: Is this with Minishift or just ``oc cluster up``?

Comment: minishift. This is my minishift command: `minishift start --openshift-version v3.7.0 --vm-driver=virtualbox --no-proxy=".cluster.local,.svc,172.30.0.1" --http-proxy=http://<host>:<port> --https-proxy=http://<host>:<port> --docker-env HTTP_PROXY=http://<host>:<port> --docker-env HTTPS_PROXY=http://<host>:<port>`

Comment: If using Minishift, you can run ``minishift docker-env`` and access it direct instead of via the route.

Answer (score 0):

If the route is configured with HTTPS and the cert is a self-signed cert then docker has to be configured to trust the cert.

Steps:

- On the host where docker is running, create a folder under `/etc/docker/certs.d/` named after the OpenShift Docker Registry URL: `mkdir -p /etc/docker/certs.d/docker-registry-default.192.168.99.104.nip.io`
- Place in that folder the cert of the CA that signed the cert of the OpenShift Docker Registry: `/etc/docker/certs.d/docker-registry-default.192.168.99.104.nip.io/ca.crt`

Comment: what exact file and location used to sign the Openshift Docker registry? Are you referring the ca.crt under ~/.minishift/ca.crt or /etc/docker/openshift.local.clusterup/kube-apiserver/ca.crt or
/etc/docker/openshift.local.clusterup/openshift-apiserver/ca.crt

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your host `/etc/hosts` file:

```
<router IP> docker-registry-default.192.168.99.104.nip.io
```

You can get the router IP by:

```
oc get svc -n default
```