# Certificate issue while trying to pull docker image

Tags: docker, docker-image, docker-proxy

Get https://registry.access.redhat.com/v1/_ping: proxyconnect tcp: x509: cannot validate certificate for xx.xx.xx.xx because it doesn't contain any IP SANs

We are running docker in RHEL7 VM in IBM cloud. The VM is sitting behind a proxy server. We have configured docker with proper HTTP & HTTPS proxy. But while trying to pull a docker image `docker pull hello-world`, it is throwing the below error.

```
Get https://registry.access.redhat.com/v1/_ping: proxyconnect tcp: x509: cannot validate certificate for xx.xx.xx.xx because it doesn't contain any IP SANs
```

Any possible resolution? 
Is there a way to disable certificate checks in docker?

Comment: Hm, do you have an idea why `docker pull hello-world` would try to access the RedHat registry? It should rather try `docker.io` How exactly did you configure the proxy access on the Docker machine?

Comment: It is actually trying to pull from both `registry.redhat.com` &`docker.io` one by one.

Comment: Then again: How exactly did you configure the proxy access on the Docker machine?

Comment: @Sibaprasad Maiti - I am facing with exactly same issue and error. have you found any solution? I have followed answer from user "apisim" from post https://stackoverflow.com/q/51045704/3437439 to expose and login to docker registry. I'm connected to proxy and facing error like Error response from daemon: Get https://docker-registry-default.192.168.99.101.nip.io/v2/: proxyconnect tcp: x509: cannot validate certificate for PROXY_IP because it doesn't contain any IP SANs. any workaround for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The connection to docker registry via proxy will fail if https is used. Maybe answer in the thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/51073963/3437439 may help copy the ca.crt(but I have not verified). However, adding the docker registry to insecure registries solved this error for me.